# How to make website auto-zoom to specific resolution?

Tags: html, css

So I have made a website that only looks ideal when it is zoomed in to a specific measurement on the web browser (by clicking Ctrl, +), and I would like it to automatically zoom in or zoom out if the resolution is different on a certain computer. How would I do this? Thankyou.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #DDDCDC;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: 1100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
a {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
.list {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 26px;
  z-index: 21;
}
.listlih:hover {
  color: #5D1CFF;
}
.listlia:hover {
  color: #D78E24;
}
.listlip:hover {
  color: #5060DF;
}
.listlic:hover {
  color: #09C03A;
}
.listlig:hover {
  color: #FF0004;
}
.myman {
  position: relative;
  width: 530px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: coopert;
  src: url(fonts/fbsbltc.ttf);
}
span {
  font-family: coopert;
}
#coopert {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  font-size: 55px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.hoverheader:hover {
  color: #D9972B;
}
#official {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 730px;
  margin-top: 468px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.firstlistt {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 920px;
  margin-top: 505px;
}
#fb2 {
  width: 35px;
}
#insta2 {
  width: 35px;
}
li.listtt {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
.homebaby:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  filter: grayscale(80%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
}
.instababy:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  filter: grayscale(80%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
}
#aboutme {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 60px;
}
#orangeback {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D78E24;
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-left: -125px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>#</title>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="images/anime1.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <a class="alist" href="#">
        <li class="listlih" id="home"><strong>HOME</li></a>
<a class = "alist" href = "#"><li class = "listlia" id = "about">ABOUT ME</li></a>
<a class = "alist" href = "#"><li class = "listlip" id = "work">PORTFOLIO</li></a>
<a class = "alist" href = "#"><li class = "listlic" id = "contact">CONTACT</li></a>
<a class = "alist" href = "#"><li class = "listlig" id = "games">GAMES</strong>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    <a class="hoverheader" href="@">
      <div id="coopert"><span>Hey</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div id="official">The Official Website of CT</div>
    <ul class="firstlistt">
      <a class="homebaby" href="#" target="_blank">
        <li class="listtt">
          <img id="fb2" src="images/facebookcircle.png" />
        </li>
      </a>
      <a class="instababy" href="#" target="_blank">
        <li class="listtt">
          <img id="insta2" src="images/instagramcircle.png" />
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    <img class="myman" src="images/jumper1.png" />
    <!-- DONT TOUCH!-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Also, I don't know if this differs on computers of different size but I would like it to auto-adjust to the dimensions when you click Ctrl, + 5 times when it is completely zoomed out.

Comment: If your website needs to *“automatically zoom in or zoom out if the resolution is different on a certain computer”* then your website is broken. So fix your website. It will be helpful to look up the meaning of the term “responsive design”. Can you be more specific about the problem you have with the current rendering of your website?

Comment: It's also worth observing the layout of StackOverflow. It doesn't change when you make your browser window smaller or wider.

Comment: @roeland I think you are talking about a different topic... My website does not change layout when the browser window is made smaller or wider... have a look at this webpage and see what I mean... (coopertimewell.com/timewell) When you zoom in/zoom out from the default resolution the image of the person does not cover the entire webpage and it looks bad.

Comment: But if you would zoom the image in it may cover the menu links or it may not fit inside the width of the window. What is the expected result when the browser window is in portrait orientation, eg. 768×1024?

Comment: This question is pretty broad... and how you solve it depends specifically on the issue you're trying to solve.  Is this just for development purpose?  If so, Developer Tools is all you need.  Do you want most all displays to match regardless of resolution?  Then consider viewport units, like `vw`/`vh`/`vmax`/`vmin` and basing everything around them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use @viewport, example is below.

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
    zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 0.5;
    max-zoom: 3;
    user-zoom: fixed;
}
```

Or you can read the reference [here](http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag-and-css-viewport/)

Hope it help.

Comment: How do I edit this so that it is the same as a user clicking Ctrl, + 5 times?

Comment: Hey this didn't do anything.

Comment: already follow the link here http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag-and-css-viewport/ ?

Comment: Yes, I copied the code and it is not auto-adjusting to 5 Ctrl, +
zoom level

Answer (score 0):

It's really annoying that I can't comment on other answers but basically what worked for me is that instead of @viewport I did:

```
body {
    zoom: 5;
}
```

Where the number after zoom is the amount of times you press Ctrl +

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beware that this is not standardized and not available in all browsers.